# How to use query builder with sum() column and groupBy

Tags: php, laravel-4

How would I use query builder in Laravel to generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT costType, sum(amountCost) AS amountCost
FROM `itemcosts`
WHERE itemid=2
GROUP BY costType
```

I have tried several things, but I can't get the `sum()` column to work with a rename.

My latest code:

```
$query = \DB::table('itemcosts');
$query->select(array('itemcosts.costType'));
$query->sum('itemcosts.amountCost');
$query->where('itemcosts.itemid', $id);
$query->groupBy('itemcosts.costType');
return $query->get();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `groupBy` and aggregate function (`sum` / `count` etc) doesn't make sense.

Query Builder's aggregates return single result, always.

That said, you want `raw` select for this:

```
return \DB::table('itemcosts')
    ->selectRaw('costType, sum(amountCost) as sum')
    ->where('itemid', $id)
    ->groupBy('costType')
    ->lists('sum', 'costType');
```

Using `lists` instead of `get` is more appropriate here, it will return array like this:

```
[
 'costType1' => 'sumForCostType1',
 'costType2' => 'sumForCostType2',
 ...
]
```

With `get` you would have:

```
[
 stdObject => {
   $costType => 'type1',
   $sum => 'value1'
 },
 ...
]
```